# Mysql inserta menos registros desde csv

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

En este momento estoy tratando de realizar el cargue de los registros de una tabla desde un archivo con extension .csv a mysql. Mi tabla tiene cerca de 2.000 registros, pero solo se insertan alrededor de 160. Mi tabla tiene los siguientes campos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado modificar los tipos de datos de la llave primaria y llevarlo a VARCHAR e INT, pero sigo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

Agradezco si alguno ha tenido este error y me puede indicar como solucionarlo.

Gracias.

Comment: Eso puede ocurrir porque el valor de `id_supplier` se repite, y al ser llave primaria algunos registros no son insertados. ¿Verificaste eso?

Comment: Controlá los tipos de caracteres que se insertan, mysql a veces te trunca rutinas si detecta algún caracter no permitido, ej. un apostrofe o algo parecido